# Корзина для интернет магазина

Tags: корзина

Подскажите как правильно делать корзину?
Знаю, что можно хранить в сессии массив Id, можно через БД, можно через куки. 
Пока это моя первая попытка создании корзины, потому выбрал способ передачи массива через сессию.
А как всё таки правильно это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше наверное в куках (в очень редких случаях они могут быть отключены или затираться всякими расширениями или программами типа ccleaner), можно и в сессии (в таком случае если пользователь закроет браузер тогда сессия удалится), можно и в базу (здесь единственный минус это увеличится нагрузка на сервер и еще нужно будет его как то идентифицировать).

В большинстве случаев везде сделано хранение в куках.

Comment: Но вариант с сессией не является плохим тоном?

Comment: @Андрей, кому как больше нравится

Comment: А в куках можно хранить массив из Id?

Comment: @Андрей да, загонять в serialize, а когда получать unserialize

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Андрей забыл,serialize это для php было, на js добавление в куки это  `$.cookie('basket', JSON.stringify(array));`, а получение `var basket = JSON.parse($.cookie('basket'));`